# How to change the required field to read only

Tags: trigger

In the Employee tab, on Page layout salary field has been marked as required, yet we need to blank out the values against this field for any record added or updated.

Use Triggers to implement the same

The field is  custom,  it is set to required at the page layout level

Comment: bee123, welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange. Would you take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)? We do not implement requirements here, but the community can help with your *specific* questions. Your question is not very clear about what you need to do and are struggling with.

Comment: how i can change a field from required to read only

Comment: Please *edit your question* to add information. Make sure to mention, for example, whether the field is standard or custom, and if it is set to required at the page layout level, at the field level, or via a validation rule.

Comment: When people are asking for clarification, repeating the text that you already have in your question isn't very helpful (we've already read the words in your question, we're asking for more, and different, words to make things clearer). It is possible to include too many details, but that is a lot harder to do than to not include enough detail.

Comment: The impression that I get with this question is that you don't fully understand what you've been asked to do. "Required" and "Read-only" are generally mutually exclusive, and being able to blank out a field generally means that the field can't be required _nor_ read-only (the exception being using a page layout to enforce these restrictions, as appears to be your case). At any rate, I don't think there's enough detail for this question to be useful for others, so I have downvoted it. I'll also recommend going through the admin beginner and developer beginner trails over on Trailhead.

Answer (score 2):

Fields required at the page-layout level can be marked as non-required by [following these steps](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/projects/customize-a-salesforce-object/steps/create-account-page-layouts) (from Trailhead):

> [hover] over the ... field and click the Wrench icon that appears at the right.
>
> In the Field Properties area, [unselect] Required, then click OK.

Note that page-layout-level field requirement is not enforced in Apex code. A Apex trigger can set a field to any value, including `null`, even if that field is marked required on the page layout.

Comment: so we cannot implement this using trigger?

Comment: Page-level required fields and triggers have nothing to do with one another.

Comment: Why would you implement it using a trigger? In general, focus on the required outcome and not the method of implementing it, and ask people for the best way to do it.
Also, triggers act upon DML events. I don't see how a trigger, which fires when clicking Save, has anything to do with a page layout field being read-only.
If your "requirement" is to use a trigger, then it's a bad requirement and you should push back, saying that requirements generally place the outcome as more important than the method of implementing the requirement.